# Why does this jQuery show/hide toggle work and how can i make it better?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[On this page](http://85.235.23.133/test.html) 
the two on/off icons toggle between showing/hiding two rows in a table.

The jquery mechanism to keep track if a row status is shown is to check if the clickable text is "show" or "hide":

```
if ($(source).html() == "show") {
        $(source).html("hide");
        viewContainer.show();
    }
    else {
        $(source).html("show");
        viewContainer.hide();
    }
```

I get that this should work fine for regular `<a href="...">show</a>` links, where there is actual "show" or "hide" text to check for and change, but it also works on `<img>` tags that do not have any text that could alternate between "hide" and "show".

1. Why does this work?
2. What I really want to do is toggle the IMG ALT text together with the rows showing and hiding. Any clues as to how this can be done?

(Incidentally I tried chucking the code into http://jsfiddle.net/2Jj2w/2/, but it doesn't work there. Any ideas why?)

===== EDIT =======

Thanks to everyone who helped!

End result toggles the IMG ALT property and keeps check on show/hide status,
and IMG TITLE tags are toggled as well.

Proper jquery "prop" used instead of "attr".

Placekittens implemented.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'><!--mce:0--></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function toggleShowHide(id, source) {
         viewContainer = $(id);

         if ($(source).prop('alt') == "hidden") {
              viewContainer.show();
              $(source).prop('title', "Hide details");
              $(source).prop('alt', "shown");
         }
         else {
              $(source).prop('alt', "hidden");
              viewContainer.hide();
              $(source).prop('title', "Show details");
         }
    }</script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="javascript:toggleShowHide('#row1', '#toggle_row1')" ><img src="http://placekitten.com/40/40" id="toggle_row1" alt="hide" title="Hide details"  /></a> <a href="javascript:toggleShowHide('#row2', '#toggle_row2')" ><img src="http://placekitten.com/40/40" id="toggle_row2" alt="hide" title="Hide details" /></a>
    <table border="1" width="200">
        <tbody id="row1">
            <tr>
                <td>ROW1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="row2">
            <tr>
                <td>ROW2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I've seen this done by playing with the name of the image.  The same image is saved once as imagename_open.jpg and imagename_closed.jpg.  Then you can add an event to those names and you'll know what state you are in.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question.  Don't rely on jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm guessing it works because the browser(s) you have tested it in allow html content inside image tags, even though that isn't the standard.

Comment: "Why does it work?": it doesn't.  The 'else' always fires.

Comment: @Prusse Thanks! I still wonder why it didn't work without the manual wrap. The jsFiddle doc states "Code entered in this panel will be placed in header’s script block, that is between <script type="text/javascript"> and </script>."

Comment: @graphicdivine if "else" always fires, it would stay hidden, no?  

[else { $(source).html("show"); viewContainer.hide();]

Comment: @sumsaricum It does put in the script tag, but also it by default places it inside another function that is called on the window's onload. I removed the extra tags in your code and changed a preference in the left panel to "no wrap" so it just places the code into the script tag without extra wrapping.

Comment: @Prusse I see the difference now, thanks again!

Comment: @Alexander Sorted, thanks, just getting to know SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only to hides and don't show the rows again. That is because to execute the code to show the condition is `$(source).html() == "show"` and for image tags it evaluates to `"" == "show"` and that is false, resulting in the else block being executed. If you play with the `className` it will work fine:

```
if ($(source).hasClass("respective_row_show")) {
        $(source).removeClass("respective_row_show");
        viewContainer.show();
    }
    else {
        $(source).addClass("respective_row_show");
        viewContainer.hide();
    }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2Jj2w/6/

Comment: Except he wanted to key off of (or at least change) the img alt attribute

Comment: Sorry missed it, my bad. Guess Nicocube's answer is better =)

Comment: @Prusse I've been mulling it over for a couple of days (rewritten the whole thing), and your idea to use Classes to store state is better than the Alt attr. I asked for Alt in the first place because I copy/pastaed the code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleShowHide(id, source) {
    viewContainer = $(id)

    if ($(source).attr('alt') == "show") {
        $(source).attr('alt',"hide");
        viewContainer.show();
    }
    else {
        $(source).attr('alt',"show");
        viewContainer.hide();
    }
}
```

This works.

Comment: Two problems with this:  1) you're changing the alt of the link, not the image 2) in jQuery 1.7 you want to use prop() not attr()

Comment: I know this is not the pure JQuery way to do it, but it's the shorter way to get things done as it was. I am a lazy bum. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions:

1. The code actually does not properly works. It is making use of an enclosing text in the image tag, i.e. `<img>show</img>`, which I do not think is a good practice. This enclosing text is obtained using `.html()` but unfortunately it returns an empty string `""` doing the `($(source).html() == "show"` statement false and then only hiding elements.
2. Below there is a working code to toggle the elements and `alt` attribute of the images as you want.

   ```
   $('img[data-toggle]').toggle(function () {
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.prop('attr', 'show');
       $($this.data('toggle')).hide();
   }, function () {
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.prop('attr', 'hide');
       $($this.data('toggle')).show();
   });
   ```

   This code requires you to add a `data-toggle` attribute instead of the inline javascript  the original example was using in the elements you want to include a toggle event. The value of the attribute is the element you want to actually toggle.

   ```
   <img src="image.jpg" id="toggle_row1" alt="hide" data-toggle="#row1"/>
   ```

   The above image will toggle element with `id` equals to `#row1`, and will toggle the `alt` attribute of the image also.

   A working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WHE9A/).

Answer (score -2):

**Edith says:**
Coercion is not the problem - it's just the unguarded *else* branch that always fires

Well it doesn't work in jsfiddle and on the site it just hides the rows so I suppose the *==* operator is the guilty one. It coerces the "show" to *true* or *1* ... to anything you are comparing it. Now that you're having this thingy in the *if* statement it just coerces it to something that at least makes the hiding work :).

See Douglas Crockford for details on coercion

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook

http://javascript.crockford.com/

Comment: `==` doesn't perform coercion into a `1` or `true` when both sides are string values.

Comment: yeah you're actually right O:-) ... but crockford.com is a good look anyway